# Add 12 months to a date string and return in same format 201301 (Ym)

Tags: php, date

How can I add months to a date string such as 201308 (for August 2013) and return it in the same format, ie 201408 (for August 2014)? I've tried:

```
$dateToDflt = "201308";
$dateToDflt = strtotime(date("Ym", strtotime($dateToDflt)) . " +12 months");
$dateToDflt = date("Ym",$dateToDflt);
```

This just brings back 12 months ahead of the today's date so I think I'm getting my time and date formats confused

Comment: What is strototime($dateToDflt) returing? Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $dateToDflt);
$date->modify('+12 months')
$dateToDflt = $date->format('Ym');
```

Or simple string manipulation including casting

```
$dateToDflt[3] = $dateToDflt[3] + 1;
```

Of course works only for years 2010 to 2018. To extend to range to 2098, add this ;)

```
$dateToDflt[2] += (int) ($dateToDflt[3] == 0);
```

http://codepad.org/43LACMoZ ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I tried your original answer as I need to be able to specify different month intervals but am getting an error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (+12 months) any ideas?

Comment: I managed to take your answer and change $date->add(new DateInterval('+12 months')) to $date->modify('+12 months') and all works great. Thanks again!